# Unknown/Unhandled Data Type(s)

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter

Please help.

I am using codeigniter/php for my website. It is working well in my localhost but when I tried to transfer it to live, it's getting an error. The error part is detected in my script where I am trying to parse a json generated in php. this is where the json is encoded :

```
function get_product_offered_json(){

    $data = [];
    $query = $this->db->get("product_smb");

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;                 
        }
        return json_encode($data);
    }else{
        return "empty";
    }

}
```

and this is where i parse it:

```
jQuery.post(base_url + "/product/smb/get_product_offered_json/",  function(data, status){

                if (data != "empty"){

                    //productOffered.prop( "disabled", false );

                    var $data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

                    productOffered.empty();
                    productOffered.append("<option value='0'>Please choose here...</option>");
```

Hope this is enough to explain my issue. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `echo` instead of `return` ,in ajax we get the output

```
 if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $data[] = $row;                 
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}else{
    echo "empty";
}
```